# How can I update data extension after clicking Submit Button in the cloudpage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, html5, cloudpage, css3

I would like to update a field name "Email_Optin" in my data extension after clicking submit button and set the Value of it to True.

Is this possible using ampscript?.

Thank You!

Comment: does this data extension have a primary key?

Comment: @TravisNaughton, yes it has primary key.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could go about this. One fairly simple way would be to pass value on the submit button and update the data extension with AMPscript. I'm not sure what value you are using for your primary key but this example uses the subscriber key

E.G.

```
%%[
  Var @Submit
  Set @Submit = RequestParameter('submit')
  If @Submit == 'Submit' Then
    UpdateData('Data Extension Name',1,'PrimaryKeyField',_SubscriberKey,'Email_Optin','True')
  Endif
]%%

<form>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

- [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)
- [UpdateData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatedata.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your forms are set up, you can also use RequestParameter as per Travis' response and then use [UpsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm).

For example, the submit buttons on our form go through to a handler page which uses RequestParameter to obtain the values from the form, like this

```
%%[var @emailAddress, @EmailOptIn
set @email = RequestParameter("email_address")
set @EmailOptIn = RequestParameter("Email_OptIn")]%%
```

And then after you can use UpsertDE - which updates if there is an existing record with the same primary key (email_address in the above example) or adds in a new one if there isn't.

```
%%[UpsertDE("DataExtensionNameHere",1,"email_address",@email,"Email_OptIn",@emailOptIn)]%%
```

So this will update the record in your data extension using the email address as a primary key, or add a new record if it's not there.